# run innobackupex with gzip and pipe display output to file

Tags: mysql, linux, backup, percona

How is it possible to run this and output the innobackupex output to a file (but still send output to the display)?

```
innobackupex --user=root --password=pass --databases="db" --stream=tar ./ | gzip -c -1 > /var/backup/backup.tar.gz
```

I need to ouput the innobackupex log with `... completed OK!` in the last line to a file? How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of innobackup are you using?  Are you using the original release, the licensed one, or the one that Percona modified?

Comment: `http://www.percona.com/downloads/XtraBackup/XtraBackup-2.1.3/deb/wheezy/x86_64/percona-xtrabackup-dbg_2.1.3-608.wheezy_amd64.deb`

Comment: OKay, that's Percona's version.  I'm pretty sure that the useful output you're looking for is emitted over `stderr`, so anything that redirects `stderr` should capture it.  Perhaps `tee` it to a file?

Comment: `# wget http://www.percona.com/downloads/XtraBackup/XtraBackup-2.1.3/deb/wheezy/x86_64/percona-xtrabackup-dbg_2.1.3-608.wheezy_amd64.deb`
`# dpkg -i percona-xtrabackup-dbg_2.1.3-608.wheezy_amd64.deb`
`# apt-get install percona-xtrabackup`

Comment: I'm not a hardcore linux geek.. could you please produce the full syntax for me? :)

Comment: Ah, but half of all hardcore linux skills are just knowing what terms to Google for!  Try "redirect stderr" and "tee command" and you'll arrive at your answer.  FWIW, I have to look up redirecting stderr every time, and I've been doing this for fifteen years...

Answer (score 1):

I've also noticed that it is a bit challenging to save the "OK" output from xtrabackup to the log file, as the Perl script playing with tty. Here is what worked for me.

If you need execute innobackupex from the command line, you can do:

```
nohup innobackupex --user=root --password=pass --databases="db" --stream=tar ./ | gzip -c -1 > /var/backup/backup.tar.gz 2>/path/mybkp.log
```

if you need to script it and get an OK message you can do:

```
/bin/bash -c "innobackupex --user=root --password=pass --stream=tar ./ | gzip -c -1 > /var/backup/backup.tar.gz" 2>/path/mybkp.log
```

Please note that in the second command, the double quote closes before the `2>`

Answer (score 0):

Prepend

```
2> >(tee file)
```

to your command.